# WCF Service Reports the Wrong DNS Identity from an X509 Certificate

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I'm having an odd problem relating to the service certificate for an IIS-hosted WSHttp WCF service.

This service uses message security with certificate authentication for both client and server. The service is hosted at a url similar to this:

```
http://services.mydomain.com/client.svc
```

The service's certificate has a subject name of:

```
CN = services.mydomain.com
OU = Domain Control Validated
O = services.mydomain.com
```

And a Subject Alternative Name of:

```
DNS Name=services.mydomain.com
DNS Name=www.services.mydomain.com
```

However, when the WCF client connects, the service reports back a DNS identity of `www.services.mydomain.com`, rather than the subject name of `services.mydomain.com`. This causes the WCF client to reject the response since it's connecting to `services.mydomain.com` and is expecting that to be the name that comes back.

The site that contains this application has both HTTP and HTTPS bindings, but neither of them have host names (it accepts all connections). What can I change to get the service to report the right identity?

What can I change to get the WCF service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others who might be having this issue (especially with GoDaddy-issued certificates like mine, which have the forced `www.` prefix in the alternative name), there is a [known bug in WCF that causes it to use the last DNS name in the Subject Alternative Name as the identity](http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/683178/wcf-x509-certificate-validation-only-checks-last-dnsname-in-subject-alternative-name). The workaround, unfortunately, seems to be specifying the www. prefix as the identity for the client's endpoint.

Comment: Experienced the same bug. GoDaddy adding a non-requested subject name and Microsoft being too lazy to fix bugs. And you as a service provider look like a fool to your customers >:-( Sorry needed to vent my frustration...

Comment: The link in your answer appears to be broken.  Ran into the same thing and would like to read the background on it.